# 9.2 iPhone family sharing

Tags: apple-store, family-sharing

I added my account to my uncles so now we're doing family sharing, I recently got an Apple iTunes card for 15$ and can't use it because when I try to purchase something it goes to his credit card info to verify the purchase through him but I have credit so what's going. I'm getting fed up

Comment: If you redeem the card on your appleId, it will use up the credit on your appleId first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hit redeem in the App Store. If your account is logged in, then the credit will go to your account. And apple will use the credit first.